# Is is possible to transfer two attributes within one object at once?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm already transferring the "id" through my drag and drop. But I would like to transfer a 2nd attribute "name". Is this possible and if so how would I change this in my code

```
function drag_start(event) {
    _('app_status').innerHTML = "Dragging the "+event.target.getAttribute('id');
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.getAttribute('id') );
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.getAttribute('name') );
}

function drag_drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "test_parse_example.php";

    var elem_id = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var name = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    var event_id = event.target.getAttribute('id');
    var value = event.target.getAttribute('value');
    var time = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;
    var vars = "elem_id="+elem_id+"&event_id="+event_id+"&value="+value+"&time="+time+"&name="+name;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }

    hr.send(vars); 
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Does the value for `name` become `undefined` in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.getAttribute('id') );
event.dataTransfer.setData("text1", event.target.getAttribute('name') );


var elem_id = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
var name = event.dataTransfer.getData("text1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look [this (Drag Data)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#dragdata)

You can't call DataTransfer.setData("text", "your data") twice, the second value will  override first.

The first param of setData() is mime type string, one type can just set once, if you want to set 2 value, you could:

1. use setData("text", "id,name"), and use split with "," to extract
2. use setData("application/json", '{"id":"id", "name":"name"}'), then read as a object.

example for 1st way:

```
event.dataTransfer.setData(
    "text", 
    event.target.getAttribute('id')+','+ event.target.getAttribute('name'));
```

then getData like this:

```
var val = event.dataTransfer.getData("text").split(',');
var elem_id = val[0];
var name = val[1];
```

Of course your name can't contain char ',' or you could change to other char that hard to duplicate like '^' or '%'

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understand your 1st part so I use  event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.getAttribute('id,name') ); but then how do I extract each attribute? var elem_id = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 var name = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");  Can you explain with a piece of code or in my code. sorry if Im just being silly

Comment: getData("text".split(",")[0]); is this along the lines of what you're meaning?